# Removing default file names in Django-Storages S3

Tags: python, django, filefield, django-storage

I'm using django-storages with amazon S3, and uploading image files with:

```
models.ImageField(upload_to="img=%Y-%m-%d", max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
```

When the files are uploaded to S3 however, it has the original file name attached at the end. How do I get rid of that and replace it, with say some random hash instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Supply a callable instead of a string to `upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to). The callable will be passed the instance being saved, and the filename, and will have to return the full path, including the filename -- so you can choose not to use the original filename. (You'll have to call `strftime` yourself with `datetime.date.today()`, however).